# Skip confirmation while using Install-Package?

Tags: powershell, package-management, oneget

I have added `ChocolateyGet` as a provider on Powershell so I can use it with PackageManagement (OneGet), it works but every package I try to install warns:

> https://www.chocolatey.org is not a trusted package source

Then asks for confirmation. It also asks me if I agree to the license of the package.

I wanted to make a script to automatically install some packages, but I needed this script to be unattended, and it's not possible now because it asks those two previous questions.

Is there anyway to circumvent/automatically respond these confirmations? Like the `y` or `yes` command on Linux?

Comment: I haven't tried, but `Install-Package` looks like it has both `-Force` and `-Confirm:$false` as possible parameters, have you tried either of those?

Comment: I have already tried `-Confirm`, and it doesn't work. In fact, if you use it, it won't even install your package. I'm not at home right now, but I'll try `-Force` later.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler `-Force` works, skips both confirmation prompts. Thank you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use `-Force` where there is a Force property available on any cmdlets, otherwise if there isn't but there is a confirm, you are able to use `-Confirm:$False` which acts the same as pressing Yes.

Be careful using this however as if you in fact didn't want to process the action...you don't get a second chance.

Comment: Although it does bypass a confirmation prompt, the problem with `-Force` is that it forces a reinstall of the component even if it is already installed.

Answer (score 2):

```
choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation
```

will suppress license and other prompts during install.

```
Set-PackageSource -Name chocolatey -Trusted
```

will set package source as trusted.

Comment: Instead you can use `-SkipPublisherCheck` option for Install-Module to allow untrusted package sources.

Comment: @JohnSuit `-SkipPublisherCheck` is not for allowing untrusted packages, but for [installing newer versions of a module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-6). The only way to skip confirmation with untrusted modules is through `-Force`.